# Find all the ideals and prime ideals of $F[x]\times F[x]$ where $F$ is algebraically closed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Find all the ideals and prime ideals of $F[x]\times F[x]$ where $F$ is algebraically closed.

So I am not sure what answer is expected in this question. $F[x]$ is a PID and so all of the ideals are of the form $(f(x))$ where $f$ is a polynomial. Thus all the ideals of $F[x]\times F[x]$ are of the form $(f(x))\times (g(x))$ where $g$. I do not think this can be simplified further. Next, IF $I\times J$ is a prime ideal of $F[x]\times F[x]$ then $I,J$ are prime ideals of $F[x]$. Prime ideals of $F[x]$ are maximal and are generated by irreducible polynomials. In $F$ these are the linear polynomials but $F[x]/(x-a)=F$ and $F \times F$ is not a field. Thus it has no prime ideals

Comment: Actually, a prime ideal of a ring $A \times B$ is either some $\mathfrak{p} \times B$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, or some $A \times \mathfrak{q}$ where $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal of $B$.

Comment: @Mindlack ah i forgot that the entire ring is also prime. That is the case i was missing!

Comment: @2132123 the entire ring is *not* a prime ideal. But in this setting you need it to kill off a component of the direct sum (or else the quotient will split up into a direct sum and have zero divisors). Your claim that if $I\times J$ is prime that $I$ and $J$ are prime is not quite correct.

Comment: @TokenToucan I think it is, $F[x]/F[x]=0$ which is an integeral domain.

Comment: @2132123 Prime ideals are by definition proper, and standard convention for integral domains is to have $1\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_i, i=1,2:F[x]\times F[x]\rightarrow F[x]$ the projection on the first and second factor. If $I$ is an ideal $p_i$ is an ideal. If $J$ is an ideal of $F[x], p_i^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal. If $p_1(I)$ is not $F[x]$ it is contained in $(x-a)$ and $p^{-1}(x-a)=(x-a)\times F[x]$, same thing for $p_2$,
Remark that if $I$ is maximal, it contains $F[x]\times 0$ or $0\times F[x]$ otherwise since $(a,0)(0,b)=0$, this implies that maximal ideals are $(x-a)\times F[x]$ or $F[x]\times (x-a)$.